# How to fix translations in CiviCRM 4.7

Tags: 4.7, localisation, translation, transifex

We have a localized CiviCRM instance (Dutch), and after upgrading from 4.6 to 4.7, some things are not translated. In particular, after a contact search, the tasks you can do on the results (add relationship, delete contacts) are not translated.

So I created a Transifex-account, but there it says that all strings are translated. (I tried to see the translated strings using the Transifex UI, but I always get 'There was an error connecting to server.   Reload   '.)

This was not very helpful, so I cloned the [l10n](https://github.com/civicrm/l10n)-repository from github. I looked at the .po-files, and it looks like they are automatically generated from the sources of 4.6. In 4.7, lots of strings changed, like e.g. in [7f82e636](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/7f82e636096fd2c19d51253f58600f238a5ee3dd), but the new strings are not in the po-files.

So I wonder how we'll get CiviCRM 4.7 correctly translated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exists an unresolved localization issue that probably explains your translation problems. You can see here:

[CRM-17737
New Mailer dialog seems impossible to translate](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17737)

Comment: I hacked around the problem creating an extension for CiviCRM 4.7 in Dutch: https://civicrm.org/extensions/dutch47